# Where to find source code for JS client-side of RichTextArea?

Tags: gwt, open-source

https://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwRichText

This is the server code for GWT:

```java
  /**
   * The constants used in this Content Widget.
   */
  public static interface CwConstants extends Constants {
    String cwRichTextDescription();

    String cwRichTextName();
  }

  /**
   * Initialize this example.
   */
  @Override
  public Widget onInitialize() {
    // Create the text area and toolbar
    RichTextArea area = new RichTextArea();
    area.ensureDebugId("cwRichText-area");
    area.setSize("100%", "14em");
    RichTextToolbar toolbar = new RichTextToolbar(area);
    toolbar.ensureDebugId("cwRichText-toolbar");
    toolbar.setWidth("100%");

    // Add the components to a panel
    Grid grid = new Grid(2, 1);
    grid.setStyleName("cw-RichText");
    grid.setWidget(0, 0, toolbar);
    grid.setWidget(1, 0, area);
    return grid;
  }
```

If `gwt` is an open-source project, where's the client-side source that renders that area in the browser?

The sample is really working though does it mean it does it all on the backend? Where's the source for that backend?

[image]

because i'd like to indicate which font is currently selected but it just says "font" in the menu.

[upd] no this is definitely not the backend, it's js front so there must be source for that js logic somehwhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This widget is written in Java, and compiled to JS using the [GWT Web Toolkit](https://www.gwtproject.org/), a Java-to-JavaScript optimizing compiler. The standard toolkit comes with an assortment of widgets, which includes the RichTextArea class.

The class itself can be found in the project's GitHub repo, at [`com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RichTextArea`](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/main/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RichTextArea.java)

Much of the implementation details are delegated to another class, with several subclasses, the base subclass is [`com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.impl.RichTextAreaImpl`](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/main/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/RichTextAreaImpl.java)

Note also that the CwRichText class can be found in the repository as well, in the `samples/` directory as [`com.google.gwt.sample.showcase.client.content.text.CwRichText`](https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/main/samples/showcase/src/com/google/gwt/sample/showcase/client/content/text/CwRichText.java)

---

To answer a question you asked in a comment to your own answer: While GWT provides some tools to make calls to a backend (and provides an implementation for Java Servlets), no widgets require this (except through developers adding their own calls, for example for querying a backend for paging data, etc). The `RichTextArea` widget is no exception here, the linked Java code above runs *only* in the browser, after being transpiled to JavaScript.

Comment: Hi Colin thanks for looking it up, where's the implementation of `void rightIndent();` though for example? In the first class you linked, there's just a stub of it... OK nevermind found it here https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/main/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/impl/RichTextAreaImplStandard.java#L185

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There's no javascript code for gwt editor according to http://candidtim.github.io/gwt/2010/06/25/gwt-rich-text-editor.html</strike>

^ the above is not true the gwt playground allows to edit text like on screenshot and there are no network requests to suggest otherwise.

you can use closure library editor https://google.github.io/closure-library/source/closure/goog/demos/ for the frontend

and also http://extjs.com which is now something else see http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/UsingRichTextEditorHtmlEditortoaformExtGWT.htm

Comment: where's the source code for the backend